# Translation of "Schonenhof"?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

Here is a quote from a book I'm trying to read in german:

"Karl Erikssons Haus lag in einem verwahrlosten Garten. Es war ein alter Schonenhof mit ehemals zwei Flügeln. Jetzt war der eine verschwunden, vielleicht war er abgebrannt, vielleicht abgerissen."

I'm having no luck in finding a translation for ***Schonenhof*** and ***Flügeln*** in this context.

When I google ***Schonenhof***, a city in germany comes up, and there are no definitions in duden, dict.cc or google translator. Yelp

Comment: You **need** to describe the book in your question. Don't make us guess. Please [edit].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That *Schonenhof* is probably a farm (*Hof*) typically found in the Swedish area of [Schonen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schonen)/Skåne.

I assume the larger of such farms have several wings (*Flügel* = wings, in this case of a building).

A typical Hof like that can be found [here](https://www.ferienhausmiete.de/39445.htm) or perhaps [here](http://www.bauernhofurlaub-schweden.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/00000000012.jpg).

---

*The text seems to be from a novel by Henning Mankell (one of my favourite authors), about Wallander, which generally play around Ystad, which is in Skåne.*

[Excerpt from Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=C0FQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=Karl+Erikssons+Haus+lag+in+einem+verwahrlosten+Garten.&source=bl&ots=3cwPqE3Dbi&sig=j6kEAmbgO3M4Ye4dhBj5eSLc7os&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNxK6X_cfdAhXtzIUKHazIBnkQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Karl%20Erikssons%20Haus%20lag%20in%20einem%20verwahrlosten%20Garten.&f=false).

Comment: Very speculative, as the villages and citiesin Switzerland and Germany do not connect to Sweden? How can you be sure that this is not some kind of eg *Altenteil*, formed like *Schonvermögen*. Also I see not really the wings at all in the vacation ads. (The SH is more a term of function than of form?) https://www.uibk.ac.at/germanistik/histrom/cgi/wrapcgi.cgi?wrap_config=hr_bu_all.cfg&nr=47210

Comment: The name "Karl Eriksson" looks very Swedish, so that would support the theory that "Schonen" refers to a Swedish province.

Comment: Speculative? No, not at all. And I don't understand what you are asking with "as the villages and citiesin Switzerland and Germany do not connect to Sweden?". The wings may not be visible, but I assume many of them have wings left and right of the main building, e.g. [like this example](http://www.bauernhofurlaub-schweden.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/00000000012.jpg)

Comment: LangLangC: "aus dem Schonenhof" sounds more like "aus dem Hof der Familie Schonen" (like e.g. "der Huberhof lag etwas abseits...") oder "im Gehöft Schonen" or similar. That is not "**ein** Schonenhof".

Comment: @LangLangC: the text seems to be from a Mankell novel, about Wallander, which generally play in Ystad, which is in Skåne (Schonen), Sweden. [See here](https://books.google.de/books?id=C0FQAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=Karl+Erikssons+Haus+lag+in+einem+verwahrlosten+Garten.&source=bl&ots=3cwPqE3Dbi&sig=j6kEAmbgO3M4Ye4dhBj5eSLc7os&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNxK6X_cfdAhXtzIUKHazIBnkQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=Karl%20Erikssons%20Haus%20lag%20in%20einem%20verwahrlosten%20Garten.&f=false)

Comment: Ah. Your pictures don't convince me, but name and text-quote almost do. Document that with Swedish dictionary or original text quote and in this case I'm sold. (Although the Swiss/German points would still nag *me*)

Comment: @LangLangC: then I'm afraid I may lose you, but I hope I can live with that. I won't search for original texts or similar, but you are free to do so. I am 100% sure that Mankell means a "Hof" typical for the area, and since almost all his novels play in and around Ystad, that area is the very south of Sweden. The pics are of quite common buildings in that area. No relation to Switzerland whatsoever.

Comment: I just upvoted (hope can live with that as well ;) for the Mankell part (and that there is something typical about the *Hof*, although not the houses your pictures show). –– The Swiss/German thing still lets me think that Schonenhof in that area (see my link) represents a different meaning (and equally sparsely documented in German dictionaries)

Comment: @LangLangC: You may cling on to your Swiss/German thing, but to me, that makes no sense at all. This is a Hof typical for Schonen, period. Thanks for upvote anway.

Comment: @LangLangC: ISTM that the translator(s) formed the word analogously to "Hollandrad" or "Baskenmütze", i.e. items typical for the region mentioned.

Comment: That's even better. Might be somehwere between or around Gårdstun and Villaträdgård.  –– gBooks has frustrated me enough for now, too many hits being old OCRd *ö*s and the rest with genuine *o*s inconclusive.

Answer (score 8):

We are actually looking for a translation of this term from Swedish where it reads:

> Det var en gammal **Skånegård** som en gång haft två längor.<sup>[Mankell: Handen: Ett fall för Wallander](https://books.google.de/books?id=QDabCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT12&dq=Det%20%C3%A4r%20en%20sk%C3%A5neg%C3%A5rd%20som%20en%20g%C3%A5ng%20haft%20tv%C3%A5%20l%C3%A4ngor.&hl=de&pg=PT12#v=onepage&q=Det%20%C3%A4r%20en%20sk%C3%A5neg%C3%A5rd%20som%20en%20g%C3%A5ng%20haft%20tv%C3%A5%20l%C3%A4ngor.&f=false)</sup>

The German translation for *skånegård* obviously is *Schonenhof*, a term I haven't heard before but on searches for both, *skånegård*, and *Schonenhof* we can see that it is an apparently established term for a **certain type of a Swedish farmhouse**.

*Flügel* is the German translation of *längor* which would be **wing** in English.

Comment: The most established translation I or Google could come up with is simply "old farmhouse". For a "traditional" house I would like to see some actual architectural tradition emerge from the pictures. Can you provide the link for your search that establishes that translation? (My searches and ngram point to the direction of recent invention)

Comment: @LangLangC: I must disappoint you here - there is not dictionary entry, and no clear-cut definition. After looking at pages about [skånegård](https://www.google.de/search?source=hp&ei=p3mjW7LoBYOvsQH14oSQCA&q=sk%C3%A5neg%C3%A5rd) houses I found the term "traditional Swedish" much more suitable than merely "old" (what Google translate suggested) because they are by no means all old. Not even the Swedish Wikipedia has a definition.

Comment: @LangLangC: changed to "certain type" - this may be better indeed

Comment: Still have reservations (as apparent in other comments). Still struggle with "type", "established" and the incongruence between *gård*, house and *Hof*. (the latter might be just my lack of Swedish though) However for *this instance of the word* and for going to the source it's a +1 from me. [Are we walking on a frontier spirit here?]

Comment: @LangLangC: nah - it nags if I hear an apparently easy word I did not come across before ([gård translates to *Hof, Gehöft, Gut*](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-swedish/search?term=g%C3%A5rd&q_cat=%2Fgerman-swedish%2F)) ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Schonen** is the German name of [the province Skåne in Southern Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scania).

Maybe a [Dreiseithof](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreiseithof_(Angeln)) is meant, these were quite common in the area.  The *Flügel* are the two *wings* of barns right and left of the entrance gate.

Comment: According to aerial photos of this aera, it rather seems to be a Vierseitenhof with an entrance to the yard over a corner.

Answer (score 2):

Where a dictionary does not help, an encyclopedia might:

[image]

(Brockhaus Enzyklopädie, 19. Auflage.)

Ein "

> Schonenhof

ist, wie andere bereits mitgeteilt haben, ein Bauernhof in Schonen so wie ein

> Friesenhof

ein Bauernhof in Friesland ist und ein

> Frankenhof

ein Bauernhof in Franken oder ein

> Vierkanthof

ein Bauernhof in geschlossener (fast an eine typische römische *villa rustica* erinnernde) Bauform mit Verbreitungsgebiet vom oberösterreichischen Zentralraum bis über die niederösterreichische Moststraße. Nota bene dass hier im Namen die Region nicht aufscheint, was aber für die Erscheinung, um die es hier geht - nämlich die Kategorienbildung bei Bauernhausbauformen - nicht wesentlich ist.

Relevant für die Bezeichnung als xxxx-hof ist, dass die **regionstypischen Bauformen** gewahrt sind. Jede dieser kulturhistorischen Landschaften hat(te) eine für Bauernanwesen typische Architektur und Bauweise, die wiederum bestimmt war durch die Verfügbarkeit von Materialien (Holz, Stein, Lehm, Kalk...), die Besonderheiten der Landwirtschaft (was wächst gut?), die Besonderheiten der Rechtstradition (wem gehört das Land, wie ist die Erbfolge geregelt, etc.), Klima- und Wetterbedingungen und so weiter. Damit sind Bezeichnungen wie Schonenhof, Friesenhof, Oberschwäbischer Bauernhof etc. nicht nur bezogen auf den Ort, wo der Hof sich befindet, sondern bezeichnen auch seine **typische Gestalt**.

Einige regionstypische Bauformen für Bauerngehöfte werden auf der Seite ["Bauernhof"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauernhof) bei Wikipedia vorgestellt.

#### Weiterführende Literatur

Sigrid Kleinhanns: [Der Vierkanthof und seine Bedeutung](http://othes.univie.ac.at/22454/1/2012-06-21_0455885.pdf). Nutzungswandel und Entwicklungstendenzen eines landschaftsprägenden und identitätsstiftenden Kulturgutes. Wien 2012. (Magisterarbeit, Universität Wien)

Comment: Dank dieser Antwort lerne ich von der verlinkten WP-Seite, dass ein Schonahof in Simbabwe zu suchen wäre? & ernst: Die "typische Gestalt" ist eben gar nicht klar, wird für Schweden auf WP nicht gezeigt, und in einer anderen Antwort wird einfach ein rotes Schwedenhaus (ohne Bauer, nur "ländlich") vorgeführt. Mit allen Antworten hier nähen wir uns bislang ganz gut auf der abstrakt-theoretischen Ebene; mit einigen zweifelhaften Inferenzen. – Ein Beleg für die Behauptungsklasse "typisch" (tradional etc), gern auch visuell?

Comment: @LangLangC   Wer sich für traditionelle Bauformen landwirtschaftlicher Anwesen in verschiedenen Regionen Europas (oder der Welt) interessiert, wird dazu tausend andere und bessere Quellen finden als einen Wikipedia-Beitrag. Ich verlinke auch nicht gerne auf Wikipedia-Einträge. Aber ich habe im Moment keinen Zugriff auf eine gute architekturhistorische Bibliothek. - Beim Thema "Afrika" müsste man sich erst überlegen, ob dort "Bauernhöfe" überhaupt typisch sind; oder ob man den Begriff *Bauernhof* so weit fassen will, dass auch afrikanische Wohn- und Wirtschaftsstätten umschlossen sind.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question

Answer (score 0):

Im GRIMM findet sich zwar nicht der 'Schonenhof', wohl aber der '[Schonenfahrer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS16163#XGS16163)'. (Bd. 15, Sp. 1506)

> schonenfahrer, m. bezeichnung gewisser gildenartiger genossenschaften, so genannt, weil sie ursprünglich aus seefahrern oder rhedern bestanden, die handelsschifffahrt nach Schonen oder heringsfang an der dortigen küste trieben, in Hamburg Röding bei Campe, auch in Greifswald, schonfahrer Dähnert 411b.

Überträgt man diese Bedeutung, weiß man dann, was ein Schonenhof war.

Die für dich rätselhaften 'Flügel' sind einfach die Fügel eines Gebäudes, (just as in English, the [wings](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Fl%C3%BCgel) of a building).

Comment: We have to note that Grimm's dictionary is not a good resource for a learner of German.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question